# A FirebaseFirestore GroupCollection Error automatically created by Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am noticing a strange error which seems to have randomly appeared like everything was fine yesterday.

The error concerns a group-collection get call indexed within Firestore.

The Firestore security rule for the relevant collection is:

```css
match /collectionName/{abc} {
      
 allow read: if true;
   
}
```

The group-collection query is set as follows:

```css
try {
          await _dB.collectionGroup('otherDetails').where(
              'id', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser!.uid).get().
          then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
              print(doc['fieldName']);
            });
          });
        } on Exception catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
```

I believe that the answer to resolving this problem is in the error message:

```css
W/Firestore( 9831): (24.4.3) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query( collectionGroup=collectionName where userID==gudGT2enTTOnKj0NMgqNfMZO4kS2 order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

The error message confirms that Firestore is denying read permission, but that would be because Firestore is not finding a document to return, and that doesn't mean there are no relevant documents in the Firestore - there are.

The problem is that when Firestore is creating the index, it is adding a condition of its own automatically.  The conditions I have set in Firestore are for a specific collection and a specific field, but Firestore is then adding a condition to order-by "**name**" and is not setting a name -- it is this automatically added condition that is causing zero documents to be returned and the read denial consequence, as confirmed by the error message.

Could you advise me on a solution for resolving this problem please?

Could you explain why Firestore is creating indexes in this way? ... The strangest thing about this is that I have another example of the same query with virtually the same security rule, and it works fine.

With thanks.

Comment: Collection groups require special security rules, and have nothing to do indexes.  Read the documentation about that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules

Comment: Many thanks for your response.  The info has made a difference and seems to be the solution.  I'll add a green light once I get the final result.

Answer (score 0):

This question's problem was solved by Doug Stevenson's comment, thanks again.

If I need to return to this subject again, I'd like to remind myself to beware of the options when setting up an index (count, where, order-by and limit).  In this case I needed to choose 'order-by' and pair it with the relevant field-name and 'descending'.  The error message indicates that I chose 'where' - a mistake.